# Delay on hiding the dock - Mac OS - Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, dock

Is there a way to only put a delay on the disappear time?
ex. 1 sec for appear and 10 secs delay for disappear if the mouse is not pointing in the dock? I want the dock to appear in 0 seconds, and disappears in 10 seconds if my mouse is not pointing somewhere in the dock. I want to have different behaviour on fade in and fade out..

PS: I found [Can I adjust the time delay for when the dock re-appears?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/can-i-adjust-the-time-delay-for-when-the-dock-re-appears) but this only covers the fade-in part

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicated question. I want the dock to appear in 0 seconds, and disappears in 10 seconds if my mouse is not pointing somewhere in the dock. I want to have different behaviour on fade in and fade out..

Comment: Sorry about that - if certain tags exist on a question, then my reputation privileges slap an immediate 'close as duplicate' rather than politely ask "Does this question help?"